# Calling Javascript function from InputField

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Below is how I am calling JS function from inputField :

```
<apex:inputField id="InputFieldId" onclick="restrictCurrencyValue('{!$Component.pageBlockId.PageBlockSectionItemId.InputFieldId}')" value="{!TelecomMap[key].Amount__c}" />
```

Below is my JS :

```
function restrictCurrencyValue() {
    alert("Function called");
        var amountValue = document.getElementById("{!$Component.pageBlockId.PageBlockSectionItemId.InputFieldId}");
        var enteredAmount = amountValue;
        if(enteredAmount == '')
        return false;
        var regExp = /^(?!\.?$)\d{0,6}(\.\d{0,2})?$/; //Declare Regex
        var amountVal = enteredAmount.match(regExp); 
        if (amountVal == null){
            alert("Error");
        }
}
```

Please let me know if that is the current format of calling JS.
Also any help on JS is also appreciated since I am complete rookie in that.

Comment: The answers here are great, but you'll probably want to use `onblur` instead of `onclick`, otherwise it'll happen before the user gets to input a value.

Comment: Right ! I was just testing that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct way of doing this as follows. `{!$Component.InputFieldId}` will consider entire DOM hierarchy, since you are passing that as a parameter of onclick event of that field.

> Also, that approach is specially helpful when you are displaying records dynamically and building a table. So there will be array of components. Now if you do not pass as a parameter to javascript function then you need to loop through the array and find out the field value.

If you do not pass fieldId as parameter and if you try to access that inputField from Javascript function then you have to specify entire DOM hierarchy explicitly.

```
<apex:inputField id="InputFieldId" 
    onclick="restrictCurrencyValue('{!$Component.InputFieldId}')" 
    value="{!TelecomMap[key].Amount__c}" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function restrictCurrencyValue(fieldId) {
    alert("Function called");
        var amountValue = document.getElementById(fieldId).value;
        var enteredAmount = amountValue;

}
```

Also it will work

```
<apex:inputField id="InputFieldId" 
    onclick="restrictCurrencyValue()" 
    value="{!TelecomMap[key].Amount__c}" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function restrictCurrencyValue() {
    alert("Function called");
        var amountValue = document.getElementById("{!$Component.pageBlockId.PageBlockSectionItemId.InputFieldId}").value;
        var enteredAmount = amountValue;
}
```

Comment: there's a problem in the code, to get the value from element you need to use "value" attribute. "document.getElementById" will return the element itself.

Comment: @Anshul you are correct, updated my ans

Comment: Thanks Santanu . However if I am trying to get the value in an Alert message , it's not showing up:  function restrictCurrencyValue() {
        alert("Function called"); ---------- >This is shown .
            var amountValue = document.getElementById("{!$Component.deposit.amtsec.amt}").value;
            alert("xxx"+amountValue);

Comment: did you take the first approach?

Comment: Yes . With only the inputField id.

Comment: then verify your event, may be onchange will be good fit

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Santanu's response, you can further simplify this by simply using the component's reference ("this"), as:-

```
<apex:inputField id="InputFieldId" onclick="restrictCurrencyValue(this.value)" value="{!TelecomMap[key].Amount__c}" />
```

and JS code can be:-

```
function restrictCurrencyValue(val) {
    var enteredAmount = val;
    /* YOUR CODE */
}
```